# Unity installed on one system, not on another

Tags: unity

I downloaded Ubuntu 11.04 and made a live USB, and installed ubuntu 11.04 using that USB on 2 computers. Unity works perfect on one, but does not launch on another. Also, the system on which unity does not run has better specifications.

Comment: ... better specifications?  Can you expand on this?  The key information needed is the graphics card.  What do you mean be "does not launch"?

Comment: This question appears to be abandoned, if you are experiencing a similar issue please [ask a new question](http://askubuntu.com/questions/ask) with details pertaining to your problem. If you feel this question is *not* abandoned, please flag the question explaining that. :)

Answer (score 2):

In the absence of any information of the type of graphics card or integrated graphics installed, my suggestion would be to check if there are any suggested graphics drivers to be activated in the Additional Hardware Drivers window.

Answer (score 0):

as in better processor. The one running unity does not have a graphic card!! but still it does.
"does not launch " means that ubuntu launches in the classic desktop despite having selected the "Ubuntu" option while logging in.

Comment: ok - please edit your question with the reply - the answers box is for others to suggest answers to your question.  I presume you mean by "does not have a graphics card" - it must be using some sort of integrated graphics on the motherboard.  What graphics card (or integrated graphics) is on the computer not running Unity?   Type in Accessories - Terminal, "lspci | grep VGA".  Copy and paste the output in your question.